# what is the alternative of prepare20newsgroups in the new version of mahout

Tags: hadoop, mahout

i’m new with hadoop and mahout
i want to ask “what is the alternative of prepare20newsgroups in the new version of mahout”
because when i ran the command below：

```
mahout prepare20newsgroups
```

the result is

```
ERROR driver.MahoutDriver: : Try the new vector backed naivebayes classifier see examples/bin/classify-20newsgroups.sh
```

so what can I do，thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for your Mahout release, prepare20newsgroups is deprecated, run :

Now, you have to run from $MAHOUT_HOME:

```
examples/bin/classify-20newsgroups.sh
```

[Here the jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1006) and [here](http://www.feeny.org/apache-mahout-prepare20newsgroups-in-version-7/) you can find some useful help about it.